# Do Mormon teens practice "soaking" and "jump humping"?

Tags: sexuality, christianity, twitter, lds

According to this popular post on [/r/facepalm](https://www.reddit.com/r/facepalm/comments/pv5wxl/what_a_terrible_day_to_be_literate/), [and again here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aaaaaaacccccccce/comments/pvaqea/what_he_hell/)

> Some Mormon teens have convinced themselves that putting a penis in a vagina and then not moving is not sex. That's called soaking. Jump humping is when you get someone to jump on the bed next to you soaking to get some friction going without you technically causing the movement.

Is "soaking" and "jump humping" really a thing? Urban dictionary goes back to 2010 with a definition of "soak" that explicitly mentions Mormons.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=soak) [Alpha House also mentions it.](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Funny/AlphaHouse)

[image: Meme]

Comment: Not a widely believed claim.

Comment: @Gedgar: Not hard to find the claim all over the Internet - Reddit, Urban Dictionary, Quora, a subplot to "Alpha House" (2013).

Comment: @GEdgar do you have any evidence for that?

Comment: The first practice ("soaking") is more common than simply based on religious grounds, under various other terms https://www.jacquelinehellyer.com/lovelife_blog/plugging-in ; https://muvs.org/en/topics/contraception/futile-attempts-part-2-en/

Comment: actually, even a Wikipedia article on that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coitus_reservatus which does point to some religious aspects "The Oneida Community, founded in the 19th century by John Humphrey Noyes, experimented with coitus reservatus which was then called male continence in a religiously Christian communalist environment."

Comment: The reddit comments by some people claiming to be (ex-) Mormons seem to suggest that "soaking" is at least somewhat known as an urban legend, perhaps as an actual trend, while "jump humping" seems to exist as a meme only. This is obviously far from conclusive though, but the "soaking" claim sounds far more plausible than "jump humping" to me.

Comment: On SE: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/do-mormons-practice-soaking-and-is-it-an-officially-sanctioned-activity

Comment: A quick search on Web of Science finds no scholarly research on "Mormon" + any of the words related to the topic.

Comment: https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/mormon-soaking-jump-humping